# How to Improve SQL Query Execution Performance?

Tags: sql

Query 1:

```
select a.*
from 
   (
   select 
row_number() over (order by id desc) as srno
id,name as myname,*
   from table
where name like 'search%' or column1 like 'search%' or column2 like 'search%'
or column3 like 'search%'
or column4 like 'search%'
or column5 like 'search%'
   ) a
where srno>=1 and srno<=50
```

I have 100 000 rows at my table. This query execution takes 48 second. I've applied alternate Query:

Query 2:

```
 select top 50
row_number() over (order by id desc) as srno
id,name as myname,*
   from table
where name like 'search%' or column1 like 'search%' or column2 like 'search%'
or column3 like 'search%'
or column4 like 'search%'
or column5 like 'search%'
```

Query 2 take approximate 0 second to execute 
there is indexing All ready Applied at both case

does there any Way to Execute Query 1 Within 0 Second ?

I wany to real time Execution Speed.

Comment: Where are your indexes?  What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Are there indexes on `name` and `column1` to `column5`? And I don't mean one combined index for all 6 columns, but one index for each of them? Also: How long does Query 2 take when you remove `top 50`? Because this is what's being executed in Query 1.

Answer (score 1):

No.

In the second query you are done when you have 50 records. In the first query you check all the 100.000 records and then retreive only the first 50.

Now, if you want to check only the first 50 records try something like this:

```
select a.*
from 
   (
   select 
row_number() over (order by id desc) as srno
id,name as myname,*
   from table
   ) a
where srno>=1 and srno<=5
and (a.name like 'search%'
 or a.column1 like 'search%'
 or a.column2 like 'search%'
 or a.column3 like 'search%'
 or a.column4 like 'search%'
 or a.column5 like 'search%')
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the need to use the analytic function `ROW_NUMBER()` here. Your rows can be identified by the `id`  and you are probably using the `srn` only for limiting the result to  50 rows. So, you can simply do this:

```
SELECT TOP (50)
      id
    , name AS myname 
    , *
FROM  table
WHERE name LIKE 'search%' 
   OR column1 LIKE 'search%' 
   OR column2 LIKE 'search%'
   OR column3 LIKE 'search%'
   OR column4 LIKE 'search%'
   OR column5 LIKE 'search%'
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Well with all those regex and that many rows, there is not much you can do to improve that.
I would say put some full text search field or maybe clean your input so all the data with that type of regex goes into a different table. Anyway regex is very slow if your table is going to keep growing dont expect much performance anytime soon.

Comment: It's not really a "regex."  It's a wildcard search.  And indexes ARE effective when the search literal appears at the beginning of the field, e.g. `'searchstring%'`.  However, if the *wildcard* appears as the beginning of the field, your index becomes worthless, e.g. `'%earchstring'`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are getting the same result set in both cases.

In the first statement, you are searching through the entire table, then do the filtering. The second statement just stops when it reaches the first 50 records, which is only reasonable that it is faster. Go with the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Concat the columns value and then apply LIKE operator to look for value.

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM   (SELECT Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id DESC) AS srno, 
               id, 
               name                                 AS myname, 
               * 
        FROM   mytable) a 
WHERE  ( Isnull(a.name, '') + Isnull(a.column1, '') + Isnull(a.column2, '') + 
                  Isnull(a.column3, '') + Isnull(a.column4, '') + 
       Isnull(a.column5, '') ) LIKE 'search%' 
       AND srno >= 1 
       AND srno <= 50
```

Comment: Applying LIKE to concatenated columns will make any index unusable.

Comment: There may be a chance for this. They should create  index on all these value.

Comment: ALso it would have to be `LIKE "%search%"`, so even with index on calculated column, it would be slower than the original.